# Kafka which volume to use it?

Tags: apache-kafka, bigdata, elastic-stack

I work on a log centralization project.

I'm working with ELK to Collect/Aggregate/Store/Visualize my data. I see that Kafka can be useful for large volume of data but 
I can not find information from what volume of data it could become interesting to use it.

10 Giga of log per day ? Less, more ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you want to use Kafka? I mean, it is a great tool, but what in your current requirements leads you to consider it? It's less about volume of data and more about what you want to use the data for and where you want it

Comment: I am currently doing a study to collect logs of different applications and machines. The goal is to centralize everything and this will represent an increasingly important data flow. At the moment I have an ELK infrastructure in place for some applications and there is no problem. I read that kafka is useful for a large amount of data, that's why I want to know from what volume? If it can be defined

Comment: Well, Kafka is a well proven messaging queuing system which can store the queues based on the defined retention period or for infinite time along with the event driven processing capabilities. There is no hard limit of how much data you can store, It is all relative to the hardware capacity. As Robin also mentioned,"what do you want the data for and where", you need to figure out the requirements clearly , then you can decide if Kafka seems a great fit for your use case or not. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, it's more clear for myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's approach this in two ways.

1. **What volumes of data is Kafka suitable for**? Kafka is used at large scale ([Netflix](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/keystone-real-time-stream-processing-platform-a3ee651812a), [Uber](https://www.slideshare.net/Hadoop_Summit/how-uber-scaled-its-real-time-infrastructure-to-trillion-events-per-day), [Paypal](https://conferences.oreilly.com/strata/strata-ny-2018/public/schedule/detail/69459), [Twitter](https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/topics/insights/2018/twitters-kafka-adoption-story.html), etc) and small.

   You can start with a cluster of three brokers handling a few MB if you want, and scale out from there as required. 10 Gb of data a day would be perfectly reasonable in Kafka—but so would ten times less or ten times more.
2. **What is Kafka suitable for**? In the context of your question, Kafka serves as an event-driven integration point between systems. It can be a "dumb" pipeline, but since it persists data that enables its reconsumption elsewhere. It also offers [native stream processing capabilities](https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/) and [integration with other systems](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connectapi).

   If *all you are doing* is getting logs into Elasticsearch then Kafka may be overkill. But if you wanted to use that log data in another place (e.g. HDFS, S3, etc), or process it for patterns, or filter it for conditions to route elsewhere—then Kafka would be a sensible option to route it through. [This talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bapHWhtf6fE) explores some of these concepts.

In terms of ELK and Kafka specifically, Logstash and Beats can write to Kafka as an output, and there's a [Kafka Connect connector for Elasticsearch](https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/)

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent.*